# User permission in laravel by Gate::allows

Tags: php, laravel

I have done some user permissions like "create_user","users_manage" and "normal_user". Now i have to manage the permission. I found in the userController file like this

```
public function create()
{
    if (! Gate::allows('users_manage') ) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $roles = Role::get()->pluck('name', 'name');

    return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
}
```

I have to add the "create_user" permission in that. I have tried in this way like

```
if (! Gate::allows('users_manage') || ! Gate::allows('create_user') )
```

but it is not working. Is there any other way to get the both in that. Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (! Gate::any(['users_manage', 'create_user']))
```

or

```
if (Gate::none(['users_manage', 'create_user']))
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Authorization - Authorizing Actions via Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates)

Comment: Thanks, You save my time.